# How do you get the size of the gap from LEAD or LAG?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

In my table, I have messages grouped by threads. Using `LEAD`, I can get the next message within a thread...

```
[ThreadNextMessageId] = LEAD(gm.GroupMessageId, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY gm.ThreadId ORDER BY gm.GroupMessageId)
```

But how do I tell how many rows are between the current row and the next row in the thread when ordering by GroupMessageId? The table will likely contain rows from other threads in between and I want to count those as well.

I found one way that seems to do this by enclosing my query as a CTE and then using the ID produced by LEAD to count the number of rows between the current GroupMessageId and ThreadNextMessageId, but it seems like there should be a more efficient way.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        gm.GroupMessageId
        ,gm.ThreadId
        ,[ThreadNextMessageId] = LEAD(gm.GroupMessageId) OVER(PARTITION BY gm.ThreadId ORDER BY gm.GroupMessageId)
        ,[ThreadPrevMessageId] = LAG(gm.GroupMessageId) OVER(PARTITION BY gm.ThreadId ORDER BY gm.GroupMessageId)
    FROM dbo.GroupMessage gm
)
SELECT 
    cte.GroupMessageId
    ,cte.ThreadId
    ,cte.ThreadNextMessageId
    ,cte.ThreadPrevMessageId
    ,[ThreadNextOffset] = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte c1 WHERE c1.GroupMessageId >= cte.GroupMessageId AND c1.GroupMessageId < cte.ThreadNextMessageId)
    ,[ThreadPrevOffset] = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte c1 WHERE c1.GroupMessageId >= cte.ThreadPrevMessageId AND c1.GroupMessageId < cte.GroupMessageId)
FROM cte
ORDER BY cte.GroupMessageId
```

Is there another method for counting rows between the current one and ones produced by LEAD or LAG that doesn't require a CTE - perhaps using some other SQL window function?

Comment: The next "record" (I assume you mean row) is the next one as defined by your `PARTITION BY` and  `ORDER BY` clauses. Tables are inherently unordered, so the "next" row is what ever order you define your data to be in in the query. In this case, in order of `gm.GroupMessageId` for the same value of `gm.ThreadId`.

Comment: @Larnu, yes, I can get the next row in a thread just fine. Now I want to know how many rows were between the current row and the row I found regardless of what thread they are in.

Comment: *"Now I want to know how many rows were between the current row and the row I found regardless of what thread they are in."* Like I said, tables are unordered, so this doesn't really mean anything. There are no rows "between" them unless you define an order, and like I said, in this case, those rows are "adjacent" to each other.

Comment: Perhaps sample data and expected results will help you explain what you're trying to ask here.

Comment: @Larnu, I updated my question

Comment: I can't run that statement though. That's why I asked for sampled and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest enumerating all the rows and using arithmetic:

```
WITH gm AS (
      SELECT gm.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GroupMessageId) as seqnum
      FROM dbo.GroupMessage gm
     )
SELECT gm.*,
       (LEAD(seqnum) OVER (PARTITION BY gm.ThreadID ORDER BY gm.GroupMessageId) - seqnum - 1) as messages_in_between
FROM gm;
ORDER BY gm.GroupMessageId
```

Comment: I finally got around to trying this. It works great, thanks!